# When using a button to choose a listbox item to show a string of text in a textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, listbox

*I may been unclear what my problem is with the title*

I've been working with a project for my programming class for two months now, the program is designed to help students with physics tasks, so I have a listbox with physics tasks like 2.01, 2.02 and etc. and then I have a textbox that is suppose to show a string of text example "This is how you do this task and so on..." when I choose one of the tasks with help of a button.
I have tried different methods and but none of that works, I have tried using a switch method where the task have unique case names and I have tried using IF-Statements [This explains my problem in a sense.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77wSD.png)

Comment: It is better for you to show us code you have tried so we can help you find errors in it.  Stack Overflow isn't there to write your code for you.  Having said that I've offered a piece of code to get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this, use a ListView and then just store the text in the listviewitem tag:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var lvi = listView1.Items.Add("2.01");
        lvi.Tag = "Hello";
        lvi = listView1.Items.Add("2.02");
        lvi.Tag = "Goodbye";

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
        {
            textBox1.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag as string;

        }
    }
```